# C# Call SOAP webservice with certificate, user and password

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-core, soap-client

I'm trying to call an old SOAP webservice that requires a cert on the connection + user and password
Here is my attempt:

```
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("cert.p12", "h/K3+7NpiY", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https:URL");

            SOAPClient1 client= new SOAPClient1(binding, endpointAddress);
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user._.1";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "n6k5\">rvdR";
            client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

I'm getting

{"Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: '176'."}

The certificate is correct and I'm using it with the credentials through soap-ui and it all works.

I have tried different binding options with no success